# register permissions october cms

Tags: octobercms, octobercms-plugins, octobercms-backend

I need help with registering permissions for a plugin. My plugin is 'event' and model is 'event'

1 How to define feature name in permission key.

```
acme.blog.access_categories //I don't know how to define this feature name
```

2 I need to create a permission to prevent some users from creating events in my events plugin in backend.

I have added new permission but it does nothing.
[Permission I created](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zq4HO.png)

```
 public function registerPermissions()
{
    return [
        'cng.tennis.access_events' => ['tab' => 'Events', 'label' => 'Create events']
    ];
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> **1 Feature name**

```php
public function registerPermissions()
{
    return [
        'cng.tennis.access_events' => ['tab' => 'Events', 'label' => 'Create events'],
        'cng.tennis.create_events' => [ ... ],
        'cng.tennis.list_events' => [ ... ],
        'cng.tennis.delete_events' => [ ... ],
    ];
}
```

I guess you are already adding it `'label' => 'Create events'` you can define multiple permissions there so you can assign each proper name.

**And for the key you can use like**

> **2 how to use permission**
>
> To restrict `whole event controller` you can add like this, now your whole controller is under that permission

```php
<?php namespace Cng\Events\Controllers;

use Backend\Classes\BackendController;

class Events extends BackendController
{
    public $requiredPermissions = ['cng.tennis.access_events'];
}
```

> To restrict `some specific features` suppose `create event` you need to add restrictions `manually`. for each you can add them as below

```php
<?php namespace Cng\Events\Controllers;

use Backend\Classes\BackendController;

class Events extends BackendController
{

    // other code ...

    public function create($context = null) {

        // checking permission manually
        if (!$this->user->hasPermission(['cng.tennis.access_events'])) {
            // if user do not have permission show access restricted 
            return \Response::make(\View::make('backend::access_denied'), 403);
        }

        $this->asExtension('FormController')->create($context);
    }

    // ...
```

if any doubt please comment.

Comment: Thank very much! your answer completely solved my problem.

Comment: great . nice ! ! .  :)